# Android center children in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, center, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView with an ImageView and a RelativeLayout on top of the ImageView. The RelativeLayout gets multiple ImageButtons created and assigned on runtime dynamically.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/scene"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/indoor_tour_scene_view"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                >
            </ImageView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinate_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/scene"
                >

                <!-- Mapstops will be added programmatically -->

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In portrait mode, the ImageView fills the view port and HorizontalScrollView in height, and overlaps in width so you have to scroll left right to see everything.

In landscape mode, the height is still 100% but the width will be less than the viewport due to image scale. So I want to center the views within the HorizontalScrollView.

[image]

I experienced some problems with offsets when I used `layout_gravity="center"` on the RelativeLayout. I found this blog entry https://content.pivotal.io/blog/centering-a-view-within-a-scrollview that says its an android bug, and I added the workaround as described there. It works in terms of the offset, but now my RelativeLayout `@+id/coordinate_container` fills the entire frame. That is too large and should actually match the size of the ImageView, because the dynamically created ImageButton positions are relative to the ImageView.

How can I have the child of the HorizontalScrollView centered without the offset bug, but also have the coordinate_container relative to the content of the ImageView, so it does not fill the entire frame?